# Proving $(xyz)' = x'+y'+z'$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to prove that $(xyz)' = x'+y'+z'$ using theorems/axioms.

I tried this but I just want to make sure if its the correct route or if I've done something "illegal"/wrong.

```
(xyz)' = [(xy)z]' by associativity 
       = [(x*y)'+z'] by DeMorgan's Law
       = [(x'+y') + z'] by DeMorgan's Law
       = [(x'+z')+(y'+z')] by Distribution
       = x'+y'+z' by simplifying redundant z' terms.
```

Is this the correct method?

Comment: How did you apply distribution?  You already had what you wanted to prove... you just needed to drop parentheses.

Comment: It looks OK, but I guess it would be good if you had included the set of axioms/theorems that you are allowed to use (so that we can check according to them). For example, one can write $(xyz)' = x'+y'+z'$ (by DeMorgan) and that would be perfectly fine for course XYZ, but maynot be OK for course ABC. Regardless, I highly doubt that you have an axiom that says "you may simplify the redundant $z$ terms," so you may want to formalize that step.

Comment: Doug is correct, don't apply distribution just apply associativity again.

Comment: Ok. But is distribution of the z' a valid step, albeit unnecessary?

Comment: I am hesitant to say no outright, but typically you would only see distribution applied in the case a+(bc)=(a+b)(a+c) or a(b+c)=ab+ac... That "distributive" step you did is more confusing than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say you did anything "illegal", but distribution is usually used in the following manner:

$\quad (x + y)z = xz + yz\quad $ or $\quad(xy)+ z = (x+z)(y+ z)$

or the "flip side"

$\quad x(y+z)=xy + xz \quad $ or $\quad x +(yz)=(x+ y)(x+z)$

Your work was done, essentially, when you after your second application of DeMorgan's. Then, we simply use associativity again:

$$[(x'+y') + z'] = x' + y' + z'\tag{by associativity}$$

Comment: Yeah, I realized later that I applied the distribution wrong. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @amWhy: needs another TU +1